# The $n-1$ homology group of $U\setminus\{x\}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $U$ is open.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $U$ be a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n\geq 2$ and let $x\in U$. Show that $H_{n-1}(U\setminus\{x\})$ is not the trivial group.

What I know is that $H_{n-1}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})=\mathbb{Z}$ and that $U$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n}$. Can these two facts help?

Comment: Do you know that homology groups are invariant under deformation retracts?

Comment: @SteveD of course

Comment: Well, that was my hint as well... Can you do the case where $U$ is an open unit ball, with center $x$?

Comment: @SteveD yes, in this case $U$ deformation retracts to $S^{n-1}$ right?

Comment: @SteveD but for an arbitrary open set $U$, $U\setminus\{x\}$ deformation retracts to what exactly?

Comment: Well, you can restrict to the connected case, right, since the homology group is just the direct sum of the homology groups of the components. Now since $U$ is open, it contains a ball around every point...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me outline a slightly different solution.

If $A=U$ and $B=\mathbb{R}^n-\{x\}$, then

- $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}^n$
- $B$ deformation retracts to $S^{n-1}$
- $A\cap B=U-\{x\}$

Now what does Mayer-Vietoris tell you about $H_{n-1}$?

Comment: What was your original answer though?

Comment: Also, intuitively what does it mean that the n-1 homology group of a connected open set minus a point is at least $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Intuitively, there is homology contained in the punctured open ball around the missing point, and the dimension is high enough that it won't be canceled by anything else. That is, there's a sphere in that punctured open ball, and it is not the boundary of any subcomplex that U contains (or even that the whole Euclidean space contains).

Comment: My original approach was via excision/local homology, but I realized that was more complicated than it needed to be.